# How to make image blob URL persist - append image with blob URL to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, image, async-await, fetch, blob

I'm attempting to load in an image from a remote server and display it in multiple locations on the page. I first do this using fetch, creating a new Image, and converting the blob to the image src. However, only the first usage of the image seem to display.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

**How do I get the below code to display each image twice, rather than just once?**

```js
let url1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Wales_versus_New_Zealand_scrum_1905_-_cropped.jpg/800px-Wales_versus_New_Zealand_scrum_1905_-_cropped.jpg"
let url2 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/France_versus_Wales_in_rugby_union_1922_-_cropped.jpg/800px-France_versus_Wales_in_rugby_union_1922_-_cropped.jpg"


async function getImgFromUrl(url){
  let response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.blob();
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  return image;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(){
  let im1 = await getImgFromUrl(url1);
  let el = document.getElementById("pic1")
  el.appendChild(im1)
  el = document.getElementById("pic3")
  el.appendChild(im1)
  let im2 = await getImgFromUrl(url2);
  el = document.getElementById("pic2")
  el.appendChild(im2)
  el = document.getElementById("pic4")
  el.appendChild(im2)
})
```

```css
  .grid {
          display:grid;
          grid-template: auto auto / auto auto;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          grid-gap: 5px;
          max-width:500px;
          }


  img {
    max-width:250px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class = 'grid'>
    <div id = 'pic1'></div>
    <div id = 'pic2'></div>
    <div id = 'pic3'></div>
    <div id = 'pic4'></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to separate the concerns of obtaining a `src` url, and creating the image element itself.  It looks like you have a singleton image element that you are trying to append to multiple parents.  Something like

```
async function getData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.blob();

  return data;
}

function newImgFromData(data) {
  const new_img = new Image();

  new_img.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);

  return new_img;
}
```

Then using those functions, you can append as many new images as you want:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(){
  const im1 = await getData(url1);
  const im2 = await getData(url2); // These only need to be retrieved once

  // But you can use them to append children to both parent elements:
  let el = document.getElementById("pic1");
  el.appendChild(newImgFromData(im1));
  el = document.getElementById("pic3");
  el.appendChild(newImgFromData(im1));
  el = document.getElementById("pic2");
  el.appendChild(newImgFromData(im2));
  el = document.getElementById("pic4");
  el.appendChild(newImgFromData(im2));

  // You can even use the same image source as many times as you want:
  const another_el = document.getElementById("pic56");
  another_el.appendChild(newImgFromData(im1));

  const yet_another_el = document.getElementById("pic78");
  yet_another_el.appendChild(newImgFromData(im2));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a copy of the img element 2 times.
Below I provided a function to create multiple element base on the url given

```
/*url: url of the images
 *ids: array of elements to be appended with the images
 */
function append_twice(url, ...ids){
    Promise.all(ids.map(async _=>await getImgFromUrl(url)))
    .then(imgs=>{
        for(let i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).appendChild(imgs[i]);
        }
    })
}
```

and the way to use it is as such

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(){
  append_twice(url1,"pic1","pic3");
  append_twice(url2,"pic2","pic4");
})
```

## Edit

To avoid multiple call to the server, you can use [dmitrydwhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4343641/dmitrydwhite)'s suggestion as such

```
function append_twice(url, ...ids){
    Promise.resolve(getData(url))
    .then(blob=>{
        return Promise.all(ids.map(async _=>await newImgFromData(blob)));
    })
    .then(imgs=>{
        for(let i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).appendChild(imgs[i]);
        }
    })
}
```

and the request will only occur once ;)

Comment: Thank you, it looks neat, but has the slight disadvantage that it makes an additional call to the server for each copy of the image.

Comment: Yes, and you could combined with answer provided by [dmitrydwhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4343641/dmitrydwhite) for a single request per img url